# Сортировка int представленных в String по возрастанию

Tags: сортировка, java

Помогите решить задачу!

Имеется представление чисел в String;

```
String s = "1 5 8 4 12 17";
```

Как выполнить сортировку по возрастанию?

Comment: А какие у вас есть идеи? Вы столкнулись с какой-то проблемой при решении этой задачи или вам непонятно что-то конкретное? Или вы просто ожидаете, что вам решат задачу и все?

Comment: Проблема в следующем:
разбиваю строку: String[] mas = s.split("");
далее прохожу по массиву и пытаюсь отсортировать элементы пузырьком
но не знаю как сравнить два числа. метод compareTo применить не получается.

Comment: Чтобы достать интовое число можешь сделать так:   
> int number = Integer.parseInt(mas[i]);

Comment: Спасибо! получилось

Answer (score 3):

```
    String s = "1 5 8 4 12 17";
    String[] nums = s.split(" ");
    int[] ints = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.valueOf(nums[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(ints);
```

Comment: Я бы также сделал)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы считал все в какую-нибудь коллекцию интов, а потом отсортировал

Comment: Лучше в List, у него есть метод sort!

Comment: Можно и в список, если не заморачиваться сильно.

Comment: Плюсую, в лист и .sort() с компаратором. Проще, красивее и быстрее.

Comment: @Rams666 Метод sort есть и у класса Arrays.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов Не выйдет. Нет метода sort в интерфейсе List. Для сортировки по возрастанию компаратор не нужен, т.к. это естественный порядок.

Comment: @a_gura, но только метод sort у Collections принимает в качестве аргумента List

Answer (score 0):

Создайте свой класс `MyString extends String` и реализуйте интерфейс `Comparable` с методом `compareTo()`

В методе `compareTo()` надо парсить строку до `int` и если парсинг успешный сравнивать как `int` иначе `super.compareTo()`

Comment: @Barmaley Класс String объявлен как final.

Comment: Тогда надо сделать не через наследование а через инкапсуляцию:

   public class MyString implements Comparable {
     private String m_string;

     //
   }